# Does Batman have unlimited ammo?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I don't see any ammo counter on my Batarangs, Remote Batarangs, Explosive gel, etc.  Owing to Bruce Wayne's vast fortune, does Batman have an unlimited amount of these items, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You definitely aren't missing anything. Batman, in all his vast wisdom/money, manages to bring along an unlimited number of his gadgets in that tiny utility belt of his. I'm guessing it's a Dimensional Belt of Holding +1... Man I'm a nerd...

Comment: He could have had Zatana enchant it.

Comment: Or maybe he's a hollow, remote-controlled cyborg shell filled to the brim with batarangs and explosive gels. It would explain how he can take such beatings and still have the stamina and energy to beat up dozens of armed thugs :)

Comment: He shot Darkseid. He can kill Superman anytime. In some alternate worlds he has even dated Wonder Woman. Man, he can do/store/beat anyone or anything anywhere. He is Batman! :)

Comment: Maybe he picks them up every time you blink. :)

Answer (score -3):

Yeah you get unlimited ammo/gadgets. Great game batman :)  ;)